# What commands do you use to refresh your development environment with Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I guess I'm learning somewhat backwards.  I'm very comfortable with git and never used mercurial until my most recent project.

One of the things that bothers me is that sometimes I can't seem to refresh my development environment because of un-tracked file errors.  I really don't care whether files are tracked/untracked on the development server.  I'd just like to be able to pull the most recent state of the repo from bitbucket.

Unfortunately, I sometimes end up resorting to nuking the app and re-cloning.  Normally this wouldn't be that big of a deal but there are dependencies that I need to add back to the app each time I do this because they are not stored in the repo.

With git I would run...

```
git reset --hard; git checkout master -f; git pull; git checkout origin/master -f
```

What's the mercurial equivalent?  I've tried...

```
hg revert --all; hg pull; hg update;
```

Which seems to work as I would expect it sometimes.  When it doesn't work it aborts due to the untracked file errors.  I'm looking for something that works all the time.

Comment: I presume you mean `hg revert --all`, not `hg reset --all`?

Comment: yes hg revert --all, sorry about that

Comment: It's worth noting that on modern file systems re-cloning your repo is a near instantaneous action if you do it from a local clone.  `hg clone -U pristineclone newclone`.  Many folks keep a *pristine clone* around for just that reason and then clone for it for work.  Hard links (linux, windows, osx) make that fast and almost disk-space free.  There's no need to clone over the network more than once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
hg up --clean
```

That's all there is to it. (`hg up` rather than `hg update` because hg is cooler than git and allows unique abbreviations. I dislike the way when I'm forced to use git it doesn't accept `git ci` like a sane version control system. I know I could make an alias... but I haven't ever got round to it partially as I don't use it very often at all)

`hg help [command]` (or `hg [command] --help`) is useful. The help for `revert` mentions that you probably want to use `hg update -r rev` or `hg update --clean .` instead.

This will only change tracked files. Untracked files will be left alone, which I think is what you want.

Comment: And you could tack on `hg pull` at the start if you don't have the latest changesets from BitBucket.

Comment: I prefer `hg up -C`, it's quicker to type. Often followed by a `hg purge` to remove any zombie files.

Comment: @NathanE: good tips. `hg purge` would remove untracked files if desired, but it seems that that's not desired in this case. And it's an extension, so it would need to be enabled in the hgrc.